# Does not name a type error

Tags: c++

This is the dumbest little problem I am having and I CANNOT find the reason.

I am aware that there are dozens and dozens of this error already asked, but every one I read was about the order of declaration, however, I declare my struct before I use it in a function, and still get the error.

Here is the header file:

```
#ifndef GRAPH_H
#define GRAPH_H


#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Graph {

    public:
    struct Room;

    // destructor
    ~Graph();

    // copy constructor
    Graph(const Graph &v);

    // assignment operator
    Graph & operator = (const Graph &v);

    //Create an empty graph with a potential
    //size of num rooms.
    Graph( int num );

    //Input the form:
    //int -- numRooms times
    //(myNumber north east south west) -- numRooms times.
    void input(istream & s);

    //outputs the graph as a visual layout
    void output(ostream & s , string str );

    //Recursively searches for an exit path.
    void findPath( Room * start );

    //Moves room N E S or W
    void move( Room * room , string direction );

    //inputs the starting location.
    void inputStart( int start );

    //Searches the easyDelete array for the room with the
    //number "roomNumber" and returns a pointer to it.
    Room * findRoom( int roomNumber );

    struct Room
    {
        bool visited;
        int myNumber;

        Room *North;
        Room *East;
        Room *South;
        Room *West;
    };

    private:

    int numRooms;
    int _index;
    int _start;

    Room ** easyDelete;
    string * escapePath;

    Room * theWALL;
    Room * safety;
};

#endif
```

---

The specific error is: error: "Room" does not name a type, and it is talking about my

```
Room * findRoom( int roomNumber );
```

function, which is supposed to return a pointer to a "Room." **I have tried putting the actual definition of the struct where the "struct Room;" is, to no avail.**

## Edit: My apologies, it's in my .C file when I use it:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "Graph.h"
using namespace std;

...

Room * Graph::findRoom( int roomNumber )
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: There is no compile time error with this code. Check whether you are compiling the correct file or not. http://ideone.com/cjfHq

Comment: Are you certain that the compiler complains about this declaration? I copy/pasted your code into a file, and it compiles just fine. Is your compiler complaining at the point where you define the body of your function? If so, could you please post that code?

Comment: Yep, no error here.  As the other comments note either you're not compiling the right thing or the error's something to do with the definition of the function, not the declaration.  Check that the definition is `Graph::Room *Graph::findRoom(int roomNumber) { ... }`.

Comment: Please post a complete, minimal example that demonstrates the error. Please post the complete, exact error message, including line number.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

are you sure the error is pointing to this .h file? there shouldn't be this error...

if you write the implementation (in .cpp) like this

```
Room * Graph::findRoom( int roomNumber );
```

it should complain, because Room is a part of Graph:

```
Graph::Room * Graph::findRoom( int roomNumber );
```

Comment: That was the problem! Thanks!